# cluster: :clusplot axis in wrong direction

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to plot the cluster obtained from fuzzy c-means clustering.

The plot should look like this.

[image]

code for the plot

```
plot(data$Longitude, data$Latitude, main="Fuzzy C-Means",col=data$Revised, pch=16, cex=.6,
     xlab="Longitude",ylab="Latitude")
library(maps)
map("state", add=T)
```

However, when I tried to use clusplot the plot is displaying in opposite direction(both top and bottom and left and right) as below.

I wanna know if there's a way to reverse the plot to show in the order as the above picture.

Also, for the very dense area, it's hard to find the ellipse label. I wanna know if there's a way to show the label inside the ellipse instead of outside.

[image]
code for 2nd pic

```
library(cluster)
clusplot(cbind(Geocode$Longitude, Geocode$Latitude), cluster, color=TRUE,shade=TRUE, 
         labels=4, lines=0,col.p=cluster,
         xlab="Longitude",ylab="Latitude",cex=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`clusplot` is a function that performs a lot of magic for you. In particular it projects the data set - which happens in a way you don't like, unfortunately. (Also note the scales - it centered and scaled the data, too)

> `clusplot.default`: Creates a bivariate plot visualizing a partition (clustering) of the data. All observation are represented by points in the plot, **using principal components or multidimensional scaling**.

As far as I can tell, `clusplot` doesn't have map support, but you will want such a map I guess...

While *maybe* you can use the `s.x.2d` parameter to specify the exact projection (and this way disable automatic scaling), it probably is still difficult to add the map. Maybe look at the source of `clusplot` instead, and take only the parts you want?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I read the help file for `s.x.2d` parameter, but not sure how it works. Or do you know any other ways to draw circles around clusters points in R?

Comment: I don't use R enough to help you with that. I find R syntax to be too chaotic, I really don't like it. The parameter is not well documented (only one of three parameters is somewhat documented...), you really need to look at the source, I guess.